# Show placeholder as label when focus on textbox for not "required" textboxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show placeholder as label when i click the textbox. i did with "required" textboxes.

```
<input type="text" class="inputText" required>
```

But how to achieve this without required like:

```
<input type="text" class="inputText">
```

I tried https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/3680/

Comment: It's not really clear what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the

```
.user-input-wrp .inputText:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label
```

part of your css because you are apply the "focus" style when the field is ":valid". If it's not required, then it's automatically "valid".

Comment: If i remove that line , that label will come again when focus is not in that textbox. when data is in textbox  label should be in top, otherwise it will be in placeholder.

Comment: Try using the :placeholder-shown property like this: `.user-input-wrp input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .floating-label`. Then you also need to set the `placeholer=" "` equal to a space on the `<input>` element in the dom. The :placeholder-shown isn't supported by IE though. So if that's a concern then this might not be a solution. Update to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/3684/